# Inject A Class into InfiniSpan Listener

Tags: java, infinispan

I tried to inject a class into an `infinispan` Listener; unfortunately inject operation doesn't work and myObject is always null; i try to inject object a belong to class MyClass;
    However method `a.doSomething()` launch always throws `NullPointerException` because a is not inject correctly. There is a way to solve this problem with cdi injection?

```
    enter code here



package org.infinispan.quickstart.jbossas7;

import org.infinispan.notifications.Listener;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.annotation.CacheEntryActivated;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.annotation.CacheEntryCreated;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.annotation.CacheEntryLoaded;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.annotation.CacheEntryRemoved;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryActivatedEvent;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryCreatedEvent;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryLoadedEvent;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryRemovedEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * An Infinispan listener that simply logs cache entries being created and removed
 * 
 * @author Pete Muir
 * 
 */
@Listener
public class LoggingListener {

    private static final String myClassName = LoggingListener.class.getName();
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myClassName);

    @Inject
    MyClass a;

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LoggingListener.class);

    @CacheEntryCreated
    public void observeAdd(CacheEntryCreatedEvent<?, ?> event) {
        log.infof("Cache entry with key {} added in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        logger.info("Cache entry with key {} added in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        a.domSomething();
    }

    @CacheEntryRemoved
    public void observeRemove(CacheEntryRemovedEvent<?, ?> event) {
        log.infof("Cache entry with key {} removed in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        logger.info("Cache entry with key {} removed in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        a.domSomething();
    }

    @CacheEntryLoaded
    public void observeLoad(CacheEntryLoadedEvent<?, ?> event) {
        log.infof("Cache entry with key {} added in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        logger.info("Cache entry with key {} loaded in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        a.domSomething();
    }

    @CacheEntryActivated
    public void observeActivate(CacheEntryActivatedEvent<?, ?> event) {
        log.infof("Cache entry with key {} added in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        logger.info("Cache entry with key {} activated in cache {}", event.getKey(), event.getCache());
        a.domSomething();
    }

}
```

Comment: Injections only work if the class is instantiated by your CDI system.  I guess it is created somewhere else or by you directly.  Without knowing how it is created I can't help you further.

Comment: Class a is inject by cdiSystem; i could post my class a but when i inject class a outside infinispan Listener, injection operation works fine. In my opinione, infinispan Listener is outside cdi context.

Comment: I don't mean `MyClass`, I mean who is creating `LoggingListener`...

Comment: ok i don't understand, Logging Listener is createdy by Myclass Class. This is the code:
MyClass:
----code ------

@PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        logger.info("Post Construct ConfigurationManager");
        cache = this.cacheManager.getCache("dist");
        logger.info("Cache :"+cache.getName());
        cache.addListener(new LoggingListener());
        reloadConfigurations();
    }

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-jdg-quickstarts/blob/jdg-7.3.x/cdi-jdg/README.md

Comment: I'm not expert in CDI, but I agree with the comments from @john16384, you probably would need this listener class to be instantiated by CDI to get it to work. As a last resort, you can always create a constructor in Listener class that takes MyClass :)